# What is the number of combinations of 3 binary inputs given number of operators?

Tags: input, binary, logic, combinations, permutation

I am looking to find out what the possible combinations of 3 binary inputs, A,B and C, (using all of them) would be given the range of operators between them available. We have OR, AND, XOR and NOT available, and I concluded with this list:

```
A & (B & C), !A & (B & C), !A & (!B & C), !A & (!B & !C)
A & (B | C), !A & (B | C), !A & (!B | C), !A & (!B | !C)
A & (B ^ C), !A & (B ^ C), !A & (!B ^ C), !A & (!B ^ !C)

A | (B & C), !A | (B & C), !A | (!B & C), !A | (!B & !C)
A | (B | C), !A | (B | C), !A | (!B | C), !A | (!B | !C)
A | (B ^ C), !A | (B ^ C), !A | (!B ^ C), !A | (!B ^ !C)

A ^ (B & C), !A ^ (B & C), !A ^ (!B & C), !A ^ (!B & !C)
A ^ (B | C), !A ^ (B | C), !A ^ (!B | C), !A ^ (!B | !C)
A ^ (B ^ C), !A ^ (B ^ C), !A ^ (!B ^ C), !A ^ (!B ^ !C)
```

Does this account for all combinations between A, B and C using the operators? Is there a way to calculate this amount of combinations instead of my having to do this by hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this account for all combinations between A, B and C using the operators?

It depends on what your rules are, but given reasonable rules, I would think not. I don't see `A & (!B & !C)`, for instance.

> Is there a way to calculate this amount of combinations instead of my having to do this by hand?

Write down what the rules are for an expression being of your form. Be specific. Do `A`, `B` and `C` each appear exactly once? Can any number - 0, 1, 2 or 3 - of these be negated in any expression? Are the parentheses always around the rightmost operation and never the leftmost? Can the parenthesized expression be negated? Confirming things like multiple negation being disallowed would also show you've considered that possibility.

Once you have the rules, you can go through the required components and limitations on your expressions and say how many options you have for satisfying every requirement subject to every constraint. For instance, assuming `A, B, C` show up exactly once and in that order, that each variable may be negated or not, and that the binary operators may be chosen freely and independently, I get:

- 1 way to choose and arrange variables `A, B, C`
- 1 way to parenthesize the expression
- 2^3 = 8 ways to place negations (3 variables, one parenthesized subexpression, all either negated or not)
- 3^2 = 9 ways to choose binary operators (3 operators, two places to put them, each chosen freely)
- Total: 1 x 1 x 8 x 9 = 72 expressions

Some of these 72 expressions will be equivalent; in particular, `!X ^ !Y = X ^ Y`, `!X ^ Y = X ^ !Y`, and `X ^ !Y = !X ^ Y`, so we double counted in 1/2 cases when `^` was selected as the second operator - 1/3 of all cases. 72 x 1/2 x 1/3 = 72/6 = 12 should really have been 6. So 72-6 = 66 of our expressions remain.

But wait, remember De Morgan: `(X & Y) = !(!X | !Y)` and `(X | Y) = !(!X & !Y)`. So our expressions `!A ^ (B & C)` and `A ^ (!B | !C)` are equivalent by the same reasoning above. That is, where the leftmost operation is `^` and the `A` is negated (1/3 of cases and 1/2 of cases, respectively) we have double counted again. 72 x 1/3 x 1/2 = 72/6 = 12 should really have been 6. So 66 - 6 = 60 expressions remain.

Of course, both conditions can happen together. We need to add that back or we will have overcompensated. In 72 x 1/2 x 1/3 x 1/3 x 1/2 = 72/36 = 2 cases, we need to add back. So we have 62 logically distinct expressions, 10 expressions equivalent to some of the other 62, for a total of 72 expressions.

We would expect there to be 256 logically unique expressions over three variables (2^3 assignments to 3 variables, and 2 function values for each assignment, means 2^(2^3) = 2^8 = 256 functions). Similarly, there are 2^(2^2) = 2^4 = 16 functions over two variables, 2^(2^1) = 2^2 = 4 over one variable, and 2^(2^0) = 2^1 = 2 over no variables. Using this, we can work out how many unique functions we have over exactly three variables:

```
exactly 0: 2
    0 f = T   ***
    1 f = F   ***

exactly 1: 4 - (1 choose 0) * 2 = 2
    00 f(X) = F
    01 f(X) = !X   ***
    10 f(X) = X    ***
    11 f(X) = T

exactly 2: 16 - (2 choose 1) * 2 - (1 choose 0) * 2 = 10
    0000 f(X,Y) = T
    0001 f(X,Y) = !X & !Y   ***
    0010 f(X,Y) = !X & Y    ***
    0011 f(X,Y) = !X
    0100 f(X,Y) = X & !Y    ***
    0101 f(X,Y) = !Y
    0110 f(X,Y) = X ^ Y     ***
    0111 f(X,Y) = !X | !Y   ***
    1000 f(X,Y) = X & Y     ***
    1001 f(X,Y) = !(X ^ Y)  ***
    1010 f(X,Y) = Y
    1011 f(X,Y) = !X | Y    ***
    1100 f(X,Y) = X
    1101 f(X,Y) = X | !Y    ***
    1110 f(X,Y) = X | Y     ***
    1111 f(X,Y) = T

exactly 3: 256 - (3 choose 2) * 10 - (3 choose 1) * 4 - (3 choose 0) * 2 = 212
...
```

This implies that there are about 184 functions of three variables that cannot be encoded in this representation, or about 150 functions which require at least three variables. One function that cannot be computed by any of our expressions is: at least two of A, B and C are true. The truth table is:

```
A    B    C    f(A,B,C)
T    T    T    T
T    T    F    T
T    F    T    T
T    F    F    F
F    T    T    T
F    T    F    F
F    F    T    F
F    F    F    F
```

To see there is no expression for this, begin constructing one:

`A` is followed by `&`, `|` or `^`. If `&`, we could only have `T`s in one half but not both, but we have `T`s in both. If `|`, one half would have to be all `T`s, but neither of our halves is all `T`s. So `^` is our only option.

`A` is either negated or not. If it is negated, we need a truth table like the following for `B` and `C`:

```
B    C    g(B,C)
T    T    F
T    F    F for A=T, T for A=F
F    T    F for A=T, T for A=F
F    F    T for A=T, F for A=F
```

That is, the subexpression for `B` and `C` would depend on `A`, a contradiction. So there is no expression in our scheme that has this truth table. Here's an expression over three variables with the truth table: `(A & B) | (B & C) | (A & C)`

Answer (score 0):

What about a situation where you have the three conditions as available selections in a multi response survey instrument question, but condition A and B could not be true at the same time. (No was exclusionary so doesn't need to be considered).  My solution was that if A and B are both selected then A needs to be deducted from B results.

ie where survey instrument allows for multiple responses

A) One friend
B) More than one friend
C) Family
D) No